# Swift - Ambiguous Use of Subscript

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Total Swift noob here trying to learn how to build small applications and I've gotten to this point with the help of a friend and some source code I found on Medium. I am able to compile and run my application in Simulator, but compiling for my iPhone generates two (similar) errors.

The first error comes with this section:

```
class BubblesEnglishCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
let numberOfItemsPerRow = 3.0 as CGFloat
let interItemSpacing = 1.0 as CGFloat
let interRowSpacing = 1.0 as CGFloat
let sectionTitleKey = "SectionTitle"
let sectionItemsKey = "Items"
var data = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 40, right: 0)
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BubblesEnglishData", ofType: ".plist") {
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let allSections = dict["Sections"]
        if let selectedSections = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedSections") as? [Int] {
            for index in selectedSections {
            self.data.append((allSections![index]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It states that I am making ambiguous use of 'subscript' due to

```
self.data.append((allSections![index]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

I am also receiving the same error on the following lines of code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Configure the cell
    guard let bubbleItem = cell as? BubbleCell else {
        return
    }
    let sectionItems = self.data[indexPath.section][sectionItemsKey]
    let imageName = sectionItems![indexPath.row] as! String
    bubbleItem.configure(usingImageName: imageName)
}
```

Due to the line:

```
let imageName = sectionItems![indexPath.row] as! String
```

I'm sorry if my question is not making sense but these two errors are the only thing preventing me from compiling. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subscript a `[String: AnyObject]` dictionary with an `Int`. Make `data` an [Int: AnyObject] or get the subscripts' `String` value with `description` to fix that.

```
self.data.append((allSections![index.description]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)

let imageName = sectionItems![indexPath.row.description] as! String
```

On another note, you should avoid using implicit unwrapping (`!`), unless you are absolutely sure that the value will not be `nil`. Try using `guard let` or `if let` instead.

Comment: Or make the data dictionary a Dictionary<Int, AnyObject> instead of String.

Comment: Thank you both so much. That allowed it to compile. However, none of my assets show up and as you predicted, @the4kman, there is an error with the implicit unwrapping. This line of code is causing it:  
    self.data.append((allSections![index.description]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>), Any tips on how to rewrite this? Thank you again.

Comment: My advice would be to break your larger statements up into individual lines and then step through in the debugger.

`let a = allSections![index]`  

`let b = a as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`  

Then step through this code in the debugger and look for nil values at any point.